# How can you find the most retrieved object in your s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to know how many times a object retrieved from a aws s3 bucket. When we use aws CloudFront, we can use cloudFront popular objects report. How can i get similar report for s3

Answer (score 2):

Download metrics for individual S3 objects are not readily available, afaik.

You could derive them from one of:

- [Amazon S3 access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-s3-access-logs-to-identify-requests.html)
- [CloudTrail logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-request-identification.html#cloudtrail-identification-object-access)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @jarmod answer you can use [storage Lens](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/amazon-s3-storage-lens/), you can check the number of times an object is retrieved along with other handy metrics, some of these are free, and are automatically added to your account. (The retrieval ones are part of the advanced package which is charged independently)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53eHNSpaMJI&t=388s (minute 4:34)